# Have I proved $\sum_{i=1}^{\lg n} 2^{i-1} = \Theta(n\lg n)$?

Tags: asymptotics

I have an exercise problem and don't know why its answer is like this.
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\lg n} 2^{i-1} \in \Theta(2^{\lg n}) = \Theta(n).  $$

Regarding this equation, I think it would be, 
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\lg n} 2^{i-1} \in \Theta(\lg n \cdot 2^{\lg n}) = \Theta(\lg n \cdot n),  $$
with the proof,
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{g(n)}f(i) \le \sum_{i=1}^{g(n)}f(g(n)) = g(n)\cdot f(g(n)).  $$

My thought with this question,  $ f(n) =  2^{i-1} $ and $ g(n)= \lg n $. Then result would be $ \lg n \cdot 2^{\lg n - 1} $.

Can anyone point out where I made a mistake? (I am not asking grading mine, but tell me where I mis-think)

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/), and [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/) on asking questions about exercise problems. If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @dkaeae edited my question

Comment: @jayko03 Unfortunately, changing the question to 'find my mistake' does not solve the problems that exist with questions requesting to 'check a solution'. You can improve your question by specifically explain where and why you think you have made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument shows that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\lg n} 2^{i-1} = O(n\lg n).
$$
It doesn't show the matching lower bound, which is actually false.

Comment: I don't understand where it is from

Comment: Your proof, as you describe it, only proves the "≤" direction. You also need to prove the "≥" direction.